# Filter table so that rows where swapped column duplicates are not returned

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that records duplicate entities (a and b) in two columns.

The way the UI works is that if I go to a's page, the db is searched for a duplicate and if one is found a row is inserted like fig. 1 shows. If I navigate to b's page, another duplicate will be inserted and fig.2 is produced.

I cannot touch the code that does the inserting. I need to be able to filter this table to return only one of the rows from fig.2 (there are hundreds of rows with this mirrored data).

I have tried using cte's and self-joins to filter, but there aren't any filters I've thought to apply that work for one case and not the other.

E.g. something like:

```
Select * from duplicates d1
join duplicates d2
on Entity != Duplicate
```

...just filters out everything. My guess is the solution lies in a row numbering and a filter that excludes everything but row 1, but I'm not sure how to properly group and assign row numbers to accomplish this.

fig.1

```
Entity     Duplicate
a          b
```

fig.2

```
Entity     Duplicate
a          b
b          a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could order the two values to show first the least of the two. Then with `distinct` you'll avoid duplicates:

```
Select distinct
       case when entity < duplicate then entity else duplicate end as col1,
       case when entity < duplicate then duplicate else entity end as col2
from   duplicates
```

Or, with `union`:

```
Select entity, duplicate
from   duplicates
where  entity < duplicate
union
Select duplicate, entity
from   duplicates
where  entity >= duplicate
```

Answer (score 1):

Often the most efficient method is:

```
select d.*
from duplicates d
where d.entity < d.duplicate
union all
select d.*
from duplicates d
where d.entity > d.duplicate and
      not exists (select 1 from duplicates d2 where d2.entity = d.duplicate and d2.duplicate = d.entity);
```

This avoids the aggregation needed with `group by` or `select distinct`.  It can also make use of an index on `duplicates(entity, duplicate)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could find the duplicates first, and then filter those out.

Test data:

```
create table #testtb (
    entity varchar(10) not null,
    duplicate varchar(10) not null
);

insert into #testtb
values
('a', 'b'),
('b', 'a'),
('a', 'c'),
('c', 'b');
```

To find the duplicates:

```
select a.*
from #testtb a
join #testtb b
on a.duplicate = b.entity
where a.entity = b.duplicate
```

But this gives *both* duplicated rows, and you want to keep one of them:

```
select a.*
from #testtb a
left join #testtb b
on a.duplicate = b.entity
where a.entity = b.duplicate and a.entity > a.duplicate
```

To delete these rows from the original set:

```
select * 
from #testtb

except

select a.*
from #testtb a
left join #testtb b
on a.duplicate = b.entity
where a.entity = b.duplicate and a.entity > a.duplicate
```